# SonarQube does not indexes/find JAVA files

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Currently we are using an Sonar On-Premise installation. (7.9.3.X)

We send our Sonar Analysis via the maven goal "mvn sonar:sonar" to our Sonar Server. We have the Server URL and the authentication configured in our `.m2/settings.xml`.

If I am triggering the goal it does not select the Quality Profiles for Java.

```
[INFO] Load quality profiles
[INFO] Load quality profiles (done) | time=62ms
[INFO] Load active rules
[INFO] Load active rules (done) | time=1159ms
[INFO] Indexing files...
[INFO] Project configuration:
[INFO] 1 file indexed
[INFO] 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
[INFO] Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
```

I tried to set:

```
<sonar.java.binaries>target/classes</sonar.java.binaries>
```

For testing the "Findbugs" Way

```
<sonar.sources>src/main/</sonar.sources>
```

for testing the "Sonar Way"

and the deprecated Setting

```
<sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
```

but the configuration does not Scan for Java Files.

**The current sonar properties I set are:**

```
<sonar.host.url>https://sonar:9000</sonar.host.url>
<sonar.login>secrettoken</sonar.login>
<sonar.projectName>myproject</sonar.projectName>
<sonar.sources>.</sonar.sources>
```

In other Projects Scanning for Java files succeed.
In my effective Pom of the Project ("mvn help:effective-pom") I cannot found any exclusions nor a language "preselection".

What am I missing? Anyone else faced this Problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you share your sonar.properties that you are using and also let me know, if you are using branch analysis?

Comment: Dear sourvatta, we use SonarQube OSS therefore we do not have the "branch"-analysis feature. Kind regards sdsys22

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<sonar.sources>UTF-8</sonar.sources>
<sonar.sources>.</sonar.sources>
```

Comment: i tried with "sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF8" and "sonar.source = "." but it analyses even more XML Files X(